Postman Runner Execution By conserding data from CSV
The code shown here I was using it in pre script of postman collection
I was expecting to run events that is corresponding to the column in ChangeInventory of the CSV that will uploaded in runner set.
However only connect was being executed for each row.
console.log('Request Body:', pm.request.body.raw);

function formatDate(dateString) {
    let date = new Date(dateString);
    let formattedDate = date.toISOString().replace('T', ' ').replace('Z', '');
    return formattedDate.slice(0, -1) + '000';
}

let formattedDate = formatDate(pm.iterationData.get('DateTime'));
pm.collectionVariables.set('formattedDateTime', formattedDate);

let changeType = pm.iterationData.get('ChangeInventoryType').trim().toLowerCase();

switch(changeType) {
    case 'connect':
        pm.collectionVariables.set('currentApi', 'Connect');
        break;
    case 'placeholddis':
        pm.collectionVariables.set('currentApi', 'PlaceHoldDis');
        break;
    case 'change bin event':
        pm.collectionVariables.set('currentApi', 'Change Bin event');
        break;
    case 'front stock':
        pm.collectionVariables.set('currentApi', 'Front Stock');
        break;
    case 'autostock':
        pm.collectionVariables.set('currentApi', 'Replace');
        break;
    case 'stock':
        pm.collectionVariables.set('currentApi', 'stocking');
        break;
    case 'disconnect':
        pm.collectionVariables.set('currentApi', 'Disconnect');
        break;
    case 'dispense':
        pm.collectionVariables.set('currentApi', 'Dispense');
        break;
    case 'replace':
        pm.collectionVariables.set('currentApi', 'Replace');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('Unknown ChangeInventoryType:', changeType);
}


I can't see anything particular wrong with the logic.  Console log the changeType variable after you set it.  Also Console log the "currentApi" collection variable at the end of the script.  Does it look correct for each iteration?  How are you using the "currentApi" variable in your request body?
